# How to apply margins to SVG image in react native?

Tags: react-native, user-interface, svg, margin, figma

I'm using SVG as my login page logo. I want to display it at the top of the screen with the margin of '10' from the top, I tried to fix it but it doesn't seem to work. Is there any way to fix this? Kindly Help

Comment: You can use a container that parent of Svg component. Than style this parent.
<View style={{margin:10}} ><Svg>...</Svg></View>

Comment: Thanks for your response , Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [react-native-svg-transformer](https://github.com/kristerkari/react-native-svg-transformer) you can pass it a style property just like with any other React Element.

Otherwise, you could wrap a View around it and style it instead.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked , Much appreciated :)